# Как получить значение в реестре?

Tags: python, windows, реестр

Как получить код текущего системного языка windows 10, попробовал так

```
from winreg import *

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language")
for i in range(1024):
    try:
        keyname = EnumKey(aKey, i)
        asubkey = OpenKey(aKey, keyname)
        val = QueryValueEx(asubkey, "DisplayName")
        print(val)
    except WindowsError:
        break
```

Одни ошибки, хотя если искать по пути SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, выводит значение в реестре.Пробовал вводить InstallLanguage вместо DisplayName не помогло.

Comment: Так может нужно получать не список всех параметров ветви **Language**, а только параметр "**default**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому-то будет нужно, то сделал так

```
from winreg import *

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language")
keyname = EnumValue(aKey, 2)
print(keyname[1])
```

EnumValue - функция которая получает значение поля реестра по индексу - второе значение(2)

keyname - словарь в котором 3 значения:

1. Имя поля
2. Значение
3. Тип данных

https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#exception-changed